# How to show Header Image and Text in Customized Drawer navigation in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my React-native project I have created a Drawer navigation. In that drawer navigation I have Declared two items and created separate class for them. Now, the problem is I want to show a profile Image and text in the header section of the Drawer navigation. And the value of the Image and Text will come from AsyncStorage.

Here's the code for my project-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';
import {
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createAppContainer,
  DrawerItems,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-navigation';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <Ionicons name="md-home" size={24} color={focused ? 'blue' : 'black'} />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.paragraph}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
          }}>
          Go to profile
        </Text>

        <Text
          style={styles.paragraph}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer();
          }}>
          Toggle Drawer
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Profile extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Profile',
    drawerIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <Ionicons name="md-person" size={24} color={focused ? 'blue' : 'black'} />
    ),
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text
          style={styles.paragraph}
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
          }}>
          Go back home
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = props => (
  <ScrollView>
    <SafeAreaView
      style={styles.container}
      forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://appjs.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/brent3-458x458.png',
        }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </ScrollView>
);

const navigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home,
    Profile,
  },
  {
    // drawerType: 'back',
    // drawerPosition: 'right',
    // drawerWidth: 200,
    // drawerBackgroundColor: 'orange',
    // contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

So, now I am not getting how can I call **AsyncStorage** inside **CustomDrawerContentComponent** and get the desire value to show the user profile image and Text.

I need a solution for this.

Comment: Can CustomDrawerContentComponent not be a class that extends React.Component?

Comment: yes, It is not a class & working good. But I tried to make it a class but not working properly.